# MVC4 WebApi OData Delta<T> is not populating GUIDs or Int fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm looking to do partial updates on a web api controller action by using the Delta wrapper.

I have a model like such:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int NumVacationDays { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I have the api controller like such:

```
    public void Put(Delta<Person> person)
    {
        var p = person.GetEntity();

        Person existingPerson = _repository.Get(p.PersonId);

        person.Patch(existingPerson);

        _repository.Update();

        return;
    }
```

I make the call to the web api like such (using fiddler)

```
url: http://localhost:49933/api/Person (PUT)


Response Body
    {
      "PersonId": "b269c49f-8a90-41d6-b102-7cfba3812b1c",
      "FirstName": "sample string 2",
      "LastName": "sample string 3",
      "IsActive": true,
      "NumVacationDays": 5,
      "Salary": 6.1
    }

The controller is hit and al
```

l the data is populated other than the NumVacationDays (which is 0) and the PersonId (which defaults to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

Does anyone know why the GUIDs and int fields are not populating from the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can venture a guess for what is happening with PersonId but NumVacationDays cannot be explained. My guess is that PersonId is the key property for the Person entity and by default the ODataFormatter does not patch key properties. If you want that behavior, you can change the setting on ODataMediaTypeFormatter.PatchKeyMode to Patch.

Also, it would be interesting to see the value of person.GetChangedPropertyNames() in the action to see if PersonId and NumVacationDays actually show up there or not.

Comment: Hi RaghuRam. Thanks for the reply. Just to test your theory, I added two new columns: CompanyId which is a guid and NumDaysTaken which is an int. Both are sent as defaults (same as above). The result of GetChangedPropertyNames has the other 4 columns (FirstName, LastName, IsActive, Salary)

Comment: Are you using Delta<T> against JsonMediaTypeFormatter instead of ODataMediaTypeFormatter? It's not a supported scenario to use Delta<T> with json formatter. I have tested odata formatter and both guid and int work.

Comment: Hi Hongye, yes I am. I will look into the odata formatter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This problem is mentioned in this bug: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/562 ...Claims to be fixed but still exists in the 4.0 just released.

The problem being that Newtonsoft Json deserializes a number as Int64 which fails test that IsAssignable to an int, and so it is skipped. Similar issue for guids as strings.

You are supposed to be able to fix this by using the OData media type formatters, which are enabled by deriving from ODataController instead of ApiController. However this had no effect for me - int values still do not work (but when I change the data type to Int64, it works).

I would love to see a working example of posting json with a patch delta that contains an int.

Comment: This apparently also affects DateTimes. You can not Patch with "2015-06-17T00:00" it has to be the full "2015-06-17T00:00:00.000".  When I was testing this I noticed that the changedProperties would not return values that it could Newtonsoft Json could not deserialize (as greg pointed out) but when passing null, it always show up. So patching with Null was a great sanity check for me..